# Opposite of putchar()?

Tags: putchar

Is there an opposite to putchar() where you can pass the ascii character and it will output the numerical value?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

printf("%d\n", c);

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which language you are talking. In 'C++', you could just pass (int) ch which should return the numeraical ascii value.

Comment: Yes I was referring to C++.  Thanks!